# SignalR with Angular front-end works on localhost, but doesn't work remotely

Tags: angularjs, azure, websocket, server, signalr

I have two Azure Web App Services: front-end (written on Angular) and back-end (written in C# with SignalR). Either of them is placed on its own server, and I am trying to make front-end connect to back-end. Previously everything worked locally when I ran it on localhost, with `http`, but when I try to do the exact same thing on Azure (I replaced `localhost` with azure website domains), I get this error in Chrome:

[image]

I see that `https` is replaced by 'wss', which I guess is not fine for SignalR (because it's supposed to fall back to https/https if wss/ws is unavailable, as one of the commenters stated). So apparently my front-end can't see my backend.

What I've tried so far:

- Changing protocols to `http`, the way it was with `localhost`
- Setting backend to listening to `0.0.0.0:5000`
- Turning on Web Sockets in Azure settings (on both client and server)

What is my problem, and how do I connect my client side to the server side? Thanks.

Comment: wss is websockets. This is a transport SignalR tries to use for it's communication with the server. It will fallback to other HTTP transports if WebSockets fails. You should be seeing another transport working (unless you have config to only use WebSockets). In Azure Web Apps you need to explicitly turn on websockets. Do a quick search to find out how to do that.

Comment: @Brennan unfortunately, that didn't help, I still have the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use port 5000 on App Service. Configure your app so that it only uses the default ports when deployed (effectively port 80 and 443). WSS/SignalR works fine over these default ports.

You can also see the [list of exposed ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#app-service-ports).

Comment: Good catch, didn't notice they made the client use 5000. You shouldn't specify the port when connecting to App Service

Comment: @Brennan what do you mean by "You shouldn't specify the port when connecting to App Service"? Do I need to connect to `https://backend.azurewebsites.net`, without `:5000` in the end?

Comment: Okay, on backend I tried listening to `http://0.0.0.0:80`, but it threw an exception "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions". Is this even a right way to connect two Azure Web App Services?

Comment: @OleksandrNovik `https://backend.azurewebsites.net` sounds like the correct URL for your case

Comment: If that does not work then your configuration probably has some other issue (e.g. CORS, backend service is offline, ...)

Comment: @AlexAIT CORS errors used to be displayed in Chrome's console when I tried to run the site locally without localhost, but these errors don't appear on an Azure host, so I think the problem is not with CORS. Also I checked the process of backend, and it runs normally, so it's not down. still no idea what the problem is

Comment: @OleksandrNovik Unfortunately the only obvious error in your question is the port. You need to provide more error information if we are to provide you with help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244237/discussion-between-oleksandr-novik-and-alex-ait).

Comment: @AlexAIT I moved our conversation into a chat :)